# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL query to pull some student records from SQL database. I am getting the error `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.`  It looks like there is a column for student number which is char(15) type and throwing this error every time I put a letter in front of the student number (we have students with this case).

This works fine

```
Select * from StudentDataTable where StudentNumber = '123456789'
```

This throws the error

```
Select * from StudentDataTable where StudentNumber = 'A12345678'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing in your queries shown that would even be trying to convert to a datetime. Please show the real query. We cannot help you when you oversimplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is converting the student number to an integer in the background, so your first examples works, but your second one won't. Check what data-type student number is, it should be numeric type, INT, BIGINT etc..

Also, you should be querying without the quotes for the student number, saves SQL converting

```
Select * from StudentDataTable where StudentNumber = 123456789
```